# Dynamic width flexboxes that wrap yet keep column structure?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm looking for cards that have dynamic width to fill their container, yet be able to wrap if the card gets too small. I got it to do that. Yet I notice that the last card fills up the space that's left. I don't want it to do that. I want it to keep the same column structure. is this possible? I don't have to use flexboxes if there's another way to do it let me know.

[image]

[image]

```css
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display : flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   background:white;
}
.container > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ececec;
    margin:5px;
    min-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>Div 1</div>
    <div>Div 2</div>
    <div>Div 3</div>
    <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Here's my JSFiddle which is presently doing what the first picture is showing (which is not what I want). Is there a way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/0b5dm2t2/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0b5dm2t2/7/

Comment: thanks @connexo but now the cards are not dynamic width (they do not fill container).

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/0b5dm2t2/12/

Comment: Not with flexbox, but CSS grid can do this for you easily.

Comment: @Adam unfortunately the css grid isn't supported in the browser I am using.

Comment: @foreyez - what browser is that? The only mainstream browser that doesn't support CSS grid is <= IE 10 and Opera Mobile/Mini.  https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/#prop-grid-template-areas

Comment: @Adam long story.. but it's a c# web browser control. I need to upgrade it to get the css grid features.

Comment: @Adam actually IE11 has limited support for CSS Grid, too.

Comment: @foreyez - the short answer is no, what you are looking to do cannot be achieved with flexbox (without mucking with dummy div's) like another answer suggests.

Comment: Added a new answer that probably is exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: @foreyez Seeing as CSS support is some of an issue with your current browser setup I'll let you review a suggestion before submitting an actual answer. Would [this](https://jsfiddle.net/39c0x91x/) work for you? It's basically a combination of media queries, `nth-child`, `max-width` and `calc()` to set a max width for the last element at certain conditions.

Comment: @agrm lol that answer is pure hack. :D love it thanks. will probably mark the css-grid as the official answer tho.

Comment: @foreyez It should emulate the grid result Nedad suggested, but with IE10 support. Not sure if I'd call it a hack as selectors and properties are used pretty much as intended, but obviously stretching the rules in a creative direction :o) A fun challenge though! And several good (and different) answers.

Comment: Hope, my answer might help you.

Comment: As my answer showed, it is easy to achieve staying in your current flex box solution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with CSS grid layout, using `grid-template-columns`. With `minmax(200px, 1fr)` you can set min-width of each column to `200px` and max-width to one track of grid layout. You also need to use `auto-fit` to make tracks take full width in case there is available space.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  background: white;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: looks like this is the only real solution so far. sigh.. too bad for floats and flexboxes.

Answer (score 3):

A late answer, but here is another trick using pseudo-element that you make exactly the same as your div and you put at the end by adjusting order.

**No need** to add extra HTML

**No need** to use media query

**No need** to alter your current CSS and flex layout

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: white;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
}

.container:after,
.container:before {
  content: "";
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1;
  order: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, it does seem to work. but not as 'pretty' as selected answer.

Comment: @foreyez yes but this one is the flex one and the other one the grid one :) so am defending that it's also doable with flex ;)

Answer (score 1):

If you're determined to use `flex` (because of some other layout constraints) you could use some amount of "dummy" divs which are invisible: https://jsfiddle.net/0b5dm2t2/11/

```
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
  <div class='dummy'></div>
  <div class='dummy'></div>
  <div class='dummy'></div>
  <div class='dummy'></div>
</div>
```

Then set `.dummy` to an `opacity` of `0`

Alternatively a layout using percentages would give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

After all good answers, but here is my solution, in this case you can use `flex-wrap: wrap;` for `parent` and `flex-direction: column;` on items. For width, you can use `calc()` but i suggest you to use `@media` to keep all `items` fit on `screen`

```
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.container > div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/semicol/0b5dm2t2/21/)</kbd>

Comment: the widths are not dynamic in this solution. I'd like the boxes to fill the container.

Comment: @foreyez so instead of `min-width: 200px;` use `width: calc();` let me update the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

This should be what you're looking for.  Use the flex property to control the grow rate of the divs.

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: white;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.container>div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #ececec;
  margin: 5px;
  min-width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div 1</div>
  <div>Div 2</div>
  <div>Div 3</div>
  <div>Div 4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to play with media query:

```
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display : flex;
   flex-flow: row wrap;
   background:white;
   justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.container > div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background: #ececec;
    margin:5px;
    min-width:200px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
/* only required to left align last item, defaulting to center */
@media ( min-width: 768px ) and ( max-width: 992px ) {
  .container {
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }
}
```

Please note: I'm not able to set exact query point for you as I'm using jsfiddle window. You might fix it at your own.

https://jsfiddle.net/0sogzyw0/1/

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of the neighboring selector `+` to limit the width of divs that have at least two preceding neighbors:

```
.container > div + div + div {
  max-width: calc(100% / 3 - 15px);
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0b5dm2t2/20/